# Access Webservers on LAN over the internet

Tags: web-server, router, domain, local-area-network

I want to access the Websites hosted on the server at home from the Internet.
I have website1.mydomain.com on windows server. (192.168.1.111)
I have website2.mydomain.com on linux server. (192.168.1.112)
I want to access both sites from the internet. On the router ->port forwarding, it seems I can only forward port 80 to one internal IP. Do I need to setup a local domain server or software router to direct the traffic? Like if the request on 80 is for website.mydomain.com then send the request to 192.168.1.111

Answer (score 1):

Just pick another port on your router and port-forward that to the other server. Say you picked port 80 to forward to the windows server and port 8888 to forward to the linux server. Assuming the IP address of your router is 1.2.3.4, then you'd use these two URLs to access the two servers:

```
http://1.2.3.4/ <-- accesses the windows server
http://1.2.3.4:8888/ <-- accesses the linux server
```

Comment: Is there a way not to use the port number like (8888) at the end of the URL?

Comment: You could use a named virtualhost and mod_proxy with apache on the linux server to proxy the request through to the windows server.